# In my ajax form request is not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to give some alert message in my page but it working

This is my view code:

```
$.ajax({
    url :"<?php echo base_url();? 
     >booking/dispatch_challan/DispatchChallanController/createDispatchChallan",
    type:"POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data:$("#dispatch_challan_form").serialize(),
    data:$("#dispatch_challan_form").serialize()+'&disp_ch_ids='+allVals,
    success: function(data)
    {
     if(data.create_dispatch_challan.form_status=='false')
      {
      alertify.error('you may occured some server side errors');
      }else if(data.create_dispatch_challan.form_status=='true')
      {
    alertify.success(data.create_dispatch_challan.form_message);
    if (confirm())
     {
      alert("print");
      }else{
      alert("Do not print");
    }
    }
    }
    });
```

please give me same solution in this.

Comment: I think php script don't work in js script.
So you may create an element which can store the url string.
and in your js code, you may use this.
eg.

(html)`<div id="base-url" style="display:none"><?php echo base_url()?></div>`
(js)
`url : $('#base-url').html()`

Comment: Is create_dispatch_challan.form_status a string ('false') or a numeric/boolean value?

Comment: Please provide basic troubleshooting details and add some error handling. Take a few minutes to read [ask]

Comment: why are you passing multiple data     data:$("#dispatch_challan_form").serialize(),

Comment: "_but it working_" Not working I guess. Could you explain (in your question) a bit more what exactly isn't working? Does your Javascript fail? Why do you have two `data:` fields in that script?

Answer (score 0):

Its not OK to have a new line here

```
url :"<?php echo base_url();? 
>booking/dispatch_challan/DispatchChallanController/createDispatchChallan",
```

Try this code: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/BNjuvq1v)